# Why is the sum of the ratios of the length from a point to all sides in a polygon to the length from this side to a vertex equal to 1?

Tags: geometry

There is a point inside a polygon.
[image]

$\frac{DF}{FB}+\frac{DG}{GC}+\frac{DE}{EA}=1$

I tested and found it is 1, but why it is 1? How to prove it?

Comment: I cannot understand why that question was closed. It is clear, it is interesting, it does not seem to be redundant, and Thomas Andrews answer is remarkable.

Comment: You can consider your length fractions as area fractions, e.g.

$$\frac{DF}{FB}=\frac{\text{Area of }\triangle ADC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}$$

similarly for the other two fractions. And note that $\triangle ADC,\triangle ADB,\triangle BDC$ together form $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes. You are right.

Comment: Your question asks about more general *polygons* than just triangles. Can you give more examples on how you define "the sum of the ratio of the length from a point to all sides in a polygon to the length from this side to a vertex" for more complicated polygons?

Comment: @peterwhy On quads and above, also applies if the point is inside the polygons.

Comment: Say in a square, and the point is the centre of that square. From each vertex, the segment through the centre to "the opposite side" (?) would be twice the length just to the centre. And $4\times \frac12 \ne 1$. So I wonder how you would define the fractions and the sum.

Comment: @peterwhy  Okay. Maybe it only works in triangle.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a suitable answer for all readers, but I liked this trick, and some might find it interesting.

Back in high school, I learned a notion of weighted points for use on certain math competitions. I forget what they called it, but it was fairly slick.

A weighted point is a point and a positive real number weight.

Given $(A,a)$ and $(B,b)$ the weighted addition of these points is the weighted point $(X,a+b)$ where is in the line segment $AB$ with $\frac{AX}{BX}=\frac ba.$

If we think of $A$ and $B$ as vectors, we can write $$(A,a)+(B,b)=\left(\frac a{a+b}A+\frac b{a+b}B,a+b\right).$$

This can be seen as the center of mass of the line segment with the weights on the end.

Turns out, this addition is associative, and you get:

$$(A,a)+(B,b)+(C,c)=\left(\frac a{a+b+c}A+\frac b{a+b+c}B+\frac c{a+b+c}C,a+b+c\right).$$

In particular, if $a=\frac {FC}{AC}, b=\frac{GA}{AB},$ and $c=\frac{EB}{CB},$ we can also show $a=\frac{GB}{AB}, b=\frac{EC}{BC}$ and $c=\frac{FA}{BA},$ you will get:

$$(D,a+b+c)=(A,a)+(B,b)+(C,c).$$

This is the center of mass of the triangle with the given weights at the corners.

From $(F,a+c)+(B,b)=(D,a+b+c),$ we get $\frac{DF}{FB}=\frac{b}{a+b+c}.$ We likewise get similar ratios for the other terms of your sum, $\frac a{a+b+c}$ and $\frac c{a+b+c}.$

---

At heart, you can think of $A$ with weight $A$ as a higher-dimensional vector, $[aA,a].$ Then $(A,a)+(B,b)$ corresponds to the much more normal sum $[aA,a]+[bB,b]=[aA+bB,a+b],$ which is just the usual sum of vectors.This explains more clearly what this process is doing.

Then this process can be thought of as going into three dimensions and then projecting back to the plane.

But I think the center of mass view is easier to intuit. Basically, if we are trying to find the center of mass of set of points with weights at that point, with two points $A$ and $B$ with weights $a,b$ respectively, we can replace $A,B$ with one point $X,$ their center of mass, with weight $a+b$ and get the same center of mass of all the points.

Comment: It is too difficult for me to understand. What is (A,a)? How to understand it?

Comment: Sorry, if you aren't ready to understand this, I can't make it much clearer. $a$ is a positive weight, $A$ is a point, and we are defining $(A,a)$ as a weighted point. There are probably more direct approaches to prove this identity, but I've always liked this little piece of technology, and wanted to show it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I will understand in the future.

Comment: If you think of $A\in V$ with $V$ a vector space, then we can make this space equivalent to the usual $(V\times \mathbb R^+,+)$ by sending the weighted point $(A,a)\mapsto (aA,a).$ That makes associativity more clear.

Comment: You can almost certainly just define $a,b,c$ as above and show the ratios in your sum are $\frac a{a+b+c},\frac b{a+b+c},\frac c{a+b+c},$ in some order. But the underlying geometry is related to these weighted sums (which can also be seen as projections from $3$-dimensional space.)

Comment: Will this works in polygon, such as octagon？

Comment: @Y.zeng Not easily. There are rules like it, but the points are not on the edges. Essentially, if point $A_i$ has weight $a_i$ then if $C$ is the center of mass, and $C_i$ is the center of mass of all the points *other than* $A_i,$ you get: $$\sum_i\frac{A_iC}{A_iC_i}=1.$$ But the $C_i$ are not on the boundary of the polygon when the number of edges is more than $3.$ One generalization can be though of in terms of $n$-dimensional simplices, for $n+1$ points. The the polygon's can be thought of as flat/degenerate simplices.

Comment: Then if $A_1,\dots,A_{n+1}$ are $n+1$ points in $n$ dimensions, we can find the convex hull of these points, a generalized tetrahedron, and given any $C$ on the interior, we can define $C_i$ by drawing a line from $A_i$ to $C$ and and finding where it hits the opposite "side." Then you get the above equality. But when the $n+1$ points are confined to a too-small dinesion - say, four points on a plane - the "opposite side" is not well-defined. So it doesn't work as we'd like for polygons of more than $3$ points. @Y.zeng

Comment: May you recommand some books or links about weights?

Comment: Wish I could, but I learned it informally over 40 years ago, as a trick for a certain kind of problem. What I know is stuff I worked out after the fact. @Y.zeng

Comment: This way is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

For your example and other $3$-gons, convert the lengths fractions to area fractions:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{DF}{FB} &= \frac{\text{Area of }\triangle ADC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}\\
\frac{DG}{GC} &= \frac{\text{Area of }\triangle ABD}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}\\
\frac{DE}{EA} &= \frac{\text{Area of }\triangle DBC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}\\
\end{align*}$$

$\triangle ADC,\triangle ABD,\triangle DBC$ together partition $\triangle ABC$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{DF}{FB}+\frac{DG}{GC}+\frac{DE}{EA}
&= \frac{\text{Area of }\triangle ADC + \text{Area of }\triangle ABD + \text{Area of }\triangle DBC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}\\
&= \frac{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}{\text{Area of }\triangle ABC}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$